# Angular ui-route resolve injection issue

Tags: angularjs

I am new in Angular JS and I stack with problem with inject resolve promise to controller.

I have next code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap'])
        .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlMatcherFactoryProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.caseInsensitive(true);
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/refuel');
            $stateProvider.state('refuels', {
                url: '/refuel',
                controller: 'refuelController',
                controllerAs: 'refuelCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    $refuelsPumpsResolve: function ($http) {
                        return $http({
                            url: "http://localhost:60000/Refuels/GetUserPumps",
                            method: "GET"
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
        })
        .controller('refuelController', function ($refuelsPumpsResolve) {
            var $this = this;
            this.isOpen = true;
            this.isOpen = function () {
                $this.isOpen = !$this.isOpen
            }
            this.pumpsData = $refuelsPumpsResolve;

        });
```

However angular throws 'Unknown provider' exception for $refuelsPumpsResolve in controller.
I do not see any problem, more over the code was taken from ui-route tutorial on github.
Thanks for help

Comment: Maybe this debugging tip would help: Try removing the following list of providers on the second line one by one ($stateProvider, $urlMatcherFactoryProvider, $urlRouterProvider). You will have to comment out pieces of code where they are being referenced. Check which provider it is that is unrecognized. Note: you might have this info in the full error description already. Then check what module that provider belongs too. Make sure that module is included in line one.

Comment: @VishalKumar Thanks Kumar, but the problem is with $refuelsPumpsResolve injection in controller, looks like resolve is not working with ui-roter but it seems to work with it

Comment: Try this: comment out both the `$refuelsPumpsResolve` in the resolve object as well as the controller dependencies.  Create a dummy resolve object that returns a simple value. Inject it. If that fixes the issue, then it may be that your async rqst is error'ing out somehow and angular's DI doesn't like that?  I'm just guessing here.

Comment: Put a breakpoint (or `debugger;` statement) inside the `$refuelsPumpsResolve` function block. is `$http` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, declaring the injection as you would normally do for say, a controller:

```
resolve: {
  $refuelsPumpsResolve: ['$http', function ($http) {
    return $http({
      url: "http://localhost:60000/Refuels/GetUserPumps",
      method: "GET"
    })
  }]
}
```